# Kafka Connect InfluxDB Connector not reading data from Kafka topic

Tags: influxdb, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying Kafka Connect standalone with the [influxdb sink](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/influx.html) by lenses.io. Everything seemed to be working fine until I created some retention policies in the database, and specified one of those in the sink conf:

```
connect.influx.retention.policy=one_hour
```

Then, on starting Kafka Connect with new config, I kept getting:

```
[2019-11-25 14:54:59,067] INFO Empty list of records received. (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.influx.InfluxSinkTask:72)
```

Also no data was getting stored to influxdb:

```
> select * from req
>
```

So, I reverted the config, removing the retention policy line and restarted Kafka Connect, but still no data and same message. Also, I tried renaming the sink in order to reset offsets, still no dice.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get back to working state without retention policy & integrate retention policy correctly in the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a retention policy is used in influxdb, fully qualified measurement name needs to be used to access the contents. Also, I had changed the default policy used by influxdb (`> show retention policies`) , but the sink by default uses the `autogen` policy. In other words, following worked:

```
# With retention policy specified in config
> select * from one_hour.req
# <Lots of data>
# ...

# With retention policy not specified in config
> select * from autogen.req
# <Lots of data>
# ...
```

When I tried setting the policy as the now default `one_year`, only the measurement name sufficed, as expected:

```
# conf
# ...
connect.influx.retention.policy=one_year
# ...

# influx
> select * from req
# <Lots of data>
# ...
```

TL;DR: Retention policy needs to be specified with measurement name when not using the (currently) default retention policy for influxdb.